# Как привязать действие после компиляции Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Нужно после каждой компиляции скомпилированный файл дополнительно копировать в определенную папку.
Как такое реализовать?

Comment: post-build step?

Comment: @VladD ,а Вы с таким не сталкивались? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/586971

Comment: У нас в команде такое настроено в системе контроля версий (TFS). Как только кто-то закоммитит изменения, сервер автоматически строит новую версию и запускает тесты. Если при компиляции произошла ошибка, или тесты вылетают, тот, кто сделал коммит, получает сигнал по емэйлу.

Comment: @VladD ,а как можно параметры подставить,что б до компиляции они обрабатывались и брались из другого файла и компилятору выводилось значение?

Comment: Хм, ну, можно по-всякому. А что именно вы хотите сделать этим? Возможно, есть стандартный путь.

Comment: @VladD ,я взял в сборку обьединил 5 проектов. и тестирую то на localhost,то на др серверах. Я просто хотел,что б в одном месте поставить localhost и значение ServerIp поставилось такое во все файлы,где есть зависимости и скомпилировалось. Потом я беру и ставлю другой адрес и компилирую,а оно уже все проекты скомпилировало с тем адресом,и я взял и быстренько залил на тот сервер

Comment: Для этого по идее нужно класть общее значение в app.config или settings? И пусть все берут оттуда. Зачем кодогенерация, если можно обойтись конфигурацией или просто глобальной переменной?

Comment: Просто один из проектов,это Сервер,а другие-клиенты,которые общаются с ним. И каждый раз приходится переписывать адреса,если меняю с локалхоста на реальный сервер-минимум по 1 разу в каждом клиентском приложении,а потом обратно,если что-то доработать,что немного напрягает

Comment: Ну да, понимаю. Но тогда это нужно поместить в app.config, чтобы не перекомпилировать каждый раз, а просто отредактировать файл вручную.

Answer (score 1):

@VladD ,спасибо.
Если кому интересно, написал в свойстве проекта＞события сборки＞ событие после сборки,
 xcopy “$（TargetPath）” “C:\PathToMyFolder”