# Как подставить значения параметров из файла до компиляции?

Tags: visual-studio

Я хотел бы автоматизировать следующий процесс.Есть,скажем 5 приложений, параметры которых до компиляции могут меняться.
Например,я записываю в файл параметр ServerIp
и хочу,что б при сборке каждого из проектов значение ServerIp бралось из того файла,что б я не прописывал параметр в каждой из зборок.
А еще,не плохо было бы одной командой сразу перекомпилировать все проекты.
Как такое сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Если делать по уму то смотрите в сторону Continuous Integration(CI). Из простого и удобного удовлетворяющего вашим нуждам на ум сразу приходит Teamcity от Jetbrains, система автоматизации сборок по различным триггерам, позволяет проводить различные операции как на этапе пребилдинга так и постбилдинга, а так же очень гибкая настройка самих параметров билда.

Так же можете рассмотреть варианты Jenkins или Travis в принципе функционал у них одинаков примерно.